# Connection string does not initialize during form load in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

Hello can you help me with this problem. i do not know where the problem is, i already set the connection strings but it keeps telling me this message everytime i run the form.

> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

This is my code. The connection string is in the settings.

```
Private Sub LoadDAYS()
    sqlCon.Open()
    Try
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT * FROM UtlyDAY"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            cmbDay.Items.Add(Reader.GetString(1))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    sqlCon.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you set the `ConnectionString`-property of `sqlCon`?

Comment: I placed it in the solution property. "My.Settings" some sort of.. so that if ever i would copy the project to another computer, i can easily change the connection string, not setting it every form of my project.

Comment: Yes, that stores the string in the settings file, but doesn't set the `ConnectionString`-property of the `sqlCon`-object automatically.

Comment: But it works with my other Forms. So how will i then initiate the connection string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The ConnectionString property has not been initialized" error in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9162647/the-connectionstring-property-has-not-been-initialized-error-in-vb-net)

Comment: You did not show the code which creates the SQLConnection which you say is in form load.  Also you should not be re/using the same connection over and over.

Comment: Public Class frmSetupClassSchedule
    Dim strConn As String = My.Settings.SLCBRegistrarDBConnectionString
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)

Comment: the real problem is.. it works with the other forms. why is it that it won't work with this particular form since it has its same settings..